# Output webpack bundle with css only

Tags: webpack

I have multiple webpacks bundles, which work properly.

One bundle is built from css files only, and I managed to output a corresponding `foo.css`.

But webpack also outputs a `foo.js` file, which contains `ATTENTION: The "eval" devtool has been used...`, etc. It contains loads of stuff like `eval("__webpack_some_log_string")`. I don't need that file - that bundle is for css only.

**How do I configure a bundle to output a css file only?**

Comment: PS, my config is very complex and unfortunately I cannot post it. I'm simply interested in which part of the gigantic webpack config is related to this specific feature. I'll figure out the rest. Thank you!

Comment: @MORÈ I don't think it's an error. It's working as intended, but I don't know what part of webpack is used to configure the output of files.